# How data-secure is Macao’s mobile payment e-wallet (MPay)?

Tags: macau

I am going to be visiting Macao in the next couple of days and I am considering using [Macao’s mobile payment e-wallet (MPay)](https://www.macaupass.com/MPay). However, the Android app says that

> ...the MPay app processes the personal data of your mobile device (including
> but not only IMEI) and uploads to our system...

How data-secure is this storage? Are there any previous cases of data breaches?